# JQuery Accordion expand/collapse every header without collapsing the expanded headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm newby in JQuery world. I've decided to use JQuery accordion control for my program. But the functionality I need seems doesn't support Accordion control. I need to expand/collapse every header by clicking on it without collapsing the expanded headers.  I've found an example at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uleloy/2/edit), but it seems not working for me, I'm using JQuery UI 1.10.3. How can I resolve this? Is it possible to override the Accordion control functionality to reach the goal?

Comment: can you share your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

that example uses jQuery slideToggle function to toggle states. In JQuery there is also functions:

```
// "Open" element
$('div').slideDown();
```

and

```
// "Close" element
$('div').slideUp();
```

So for example to open all div:s under accordion:

```
$('.accordion div').slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your JS

```
$.fn.togglepanels = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
  .find("h3")
    .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
    .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
    .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>')
    .click(function() {
      $(this)
        .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
        .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s").end()
        .next().slideToggle();
      return false;
    })
    .next()
      .addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
      .hide();
  });
};

$("#notaccordion").togglepanels();\\GIVE YOUR ACCORDIONID IN THE PLACE OF **#notaccordion**
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/)

Answer (score 0):

In the jsbin exemple you provided, replace the second line with this one:

```
$accordionIO.next('div').hide();
```